# YouTube website downgrades after chrome reinstall

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

I no longer have access to the newest version of YouTube on my desktop after I reinstalled chrome. Is there anyway to somehow link me to the newest version or opt-in somehow? I'd prefer not to have to wait a couple weeks to get an update I've already had once.

edit: 
[I've found where you can opt-in for beta updates with YouTube and I'm now in all of them, but I still do not have the update.](http://www.youtube.com/testtube)

Comment: If you use another supported browser the site looks different?

Comment: When I was browsing youtube earlier I had the updated sidebar with hover support for collections. When I had to reinstall chrome, it now shows me the outdated version of youtube